What is a tool for Mac that can seamlessly modify archives? I.e., save them in the exact same format after modifying?
On Mac, if I unzip any archive, edit, and then 'compress' into .zip using the default archive tool, the format is by no means guaranteed to be the same. This will mean that the file might be considered corrupted by software attempting to read the file.
However, the default archive manager on Ubuntu, just called Archive Manager as far as I can tell, has the capability I desire, and can make edits seamlessly to archives of any supported format. I can 'extract' files, but I can also edit the temporary files the archive tool creates, and they will be saved to the archive in the same format.
I could not figure out how to download the Ubuntu Archive Manager for Mac, so what is the closest alternative?

Turns out the zip command line tool built-in on MacOS does the trick. I can add/update items from an archive using this command:
zip -j /path/to/archive.zip /path/to/file_to_add_or_update

Making the required changes, and then using the Finder Compress function adds some extra unwanted data that can interfere with 3rd party software trying to parse the archive. But the zip command does not, as long as I use the -j option.
